# kubernetes php nginx deployment share volume

Tags: php, docker, nginx, kubernetes, docker-compose

In kubernetes we try to have a immutable deployment of our PHP code by deploying the php code in a prepackaged container.

By nature kubernetes volume replace the directory with an empty volume, but I would like to keep the data of the php container so we can share that with the nginx container which has a vhost configured to connect to the php container.

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: serviceability
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
     spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-stuff-php
        image: our-php-service-in-fpm-container:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: my-volume
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      - name: my-stuff-nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: my-volume
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
      - name: my-volume
        emptyDir: {}
```

A similar setup on docker-compose works as docker-compose behaves different with regards to volumes.

How can I share the existing data in /var/www/html from my php container with the nginx container?

Comment: Although this is not recommended., Have you tried creating 2 volumes  pointing to same directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100922/sharing-a-persistent-volume-between-pods-in-kubernetes . Basically you can create volume on k8 and use it other pods by claimin https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes hasn't mechanism like docker-compose to share some folder as volume. But you can create Persistent Volume (PV) and Persistent Volume Claim (PVC) and share your data between containers.
It is described in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/)
Examples from Docs:

YAML for creating PV

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

Than you make PVC from this volume

YAML:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

Your YAML for deployment will looks like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: serviceability
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
     spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-stuff-php
        image: our-php-service-in-fpm-container:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: name: task-pv-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      - name: my-stuff-nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: name: task-pv-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
      - name: task-pv-storage
        ersistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
```

As a result you will have volume with data which you share between two container in pod.

Answer (score 0):

Ran in the same situation. This is an [example](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/php-fpm-nginx-kubernetes.html), [Attach Handlers to Container Lifecycle Events](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/) to your php-fpm image, my-stuff-php, in your case:

```
lifecycle:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp -r /app/. /var/www/html"]
```

1. Build your php-fpm with code at `/app` directory.
2. Create the shared volume with `emptyDir`, which is also the nginx document root.
3. Use `lifecycle.postStart.exec.command` as example above to copy source code to that shared volume.

But not sure if it's the best approach. Another way is to combine nginx and php-fpm in a single image.

Answer (score 0):

it look like you need a initContainer to host your source code,

then make a postStart to copy the code to a empty dir share volume,

therefore both php-fpm and nginx will share this volume

in this case if your application will write file during runtime,

both nginx and php-fpm can read the file too